# constructing polynomials by recursion in sage

Tags: recursion, sage, polynomials

I'd like to construct the following family of polynomials :

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801056/construction-of-polynomials-in-sagemath

I tried using the function 
R=PolynomialRing(QQ,'x',n) but doesn't work.
The difficulty is that I can't do recursion on the indexes of the variables.

Comment: (1) Please make your question self-contained; (2) you were asked where the "recursion" is supposed to come from, and have not explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
n=36
x=['x%d' % (k) for k in range(n)]
R=PolynomialRing(QQ,x)
x=[R.gen(i) for i in range(n)]
a=[x[k]*reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, x[:k]) for k in range(1,35)]
```

For example

```
a[7]
```

gives

```
x0*x8 + x1*x8 + x2*x8 + x3*x8 + x4*x8 + x5*x8 + x6*x8 + x7*x8
```

Comment: Wow ! Yes it's exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot !

Comment: other possibility : def polyad(P,k):
    return (P.gen(k))*sum([P.gen(i) for i in range(k)])

Comment: sorry for validating your answer so late !